Using Selenium's new webdriver feature
I've used Selenium for years but it looks like they've changed how you use it and I'm getting nothing but errors. Here's what I have tried:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge('Downloads/msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py in get_path(service, options)
     37         try:
---> 38             path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
     39         except Exception as err:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py in driver_location(self, options)
     70 
---> 71         browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
     72 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-957b8ee50b85> in <module>
      1 from selenium import webdriver
      2 # driver = webdriver.Edge()
----> 3 driver = webdriver.Edge('Downloads/msedgedriver.exe')
      4 driver.get('https://www.google.com')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py in __init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     48             options,
     49             service,
---> 50             keep_alive,
     51         )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py in __init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     49         self.service = service
     50 
---> 51         self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
     52 
     53         self.service.start()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py in get_path(service, options)
     38             path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
     39         except Exception as err:
---> 40             msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
     41             raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
     42 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py in get_path(service, options)
     37         try:
---> 38             path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
     39         except Exception as err:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py in driver_location(self, options)
     89 
---> 90         output = self.run(args)
     91 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py in run(args)
    137         if completed_proc.returncode:
--> 138             raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
    139         return result

WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser MicrosoftEdge --output json.
{'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_RELEASE_127_WINDOWS): error trying to connect: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (os error 10054)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NoSuchDriverException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-09613be0d9cb> in <module>
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Edge()
      3 # driver = webdriver.Edge('Downloads/msedgedriver.exe')
      4 driver.get('https://www.google.com')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py in __init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     48             options,
     49             service,
---> 50             keep_alive,
     51         )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py in __init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     49         self.service = service
     50 
---> 51         self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
     52 
     53         self.service.start()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py in get_path(service, options)
     39         except Exception as err:
     40             msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
---> 41             raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
     42 
     43         if path is None or not Path(path).is_file():

NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

I've tried different tips but want to avoid downloading itself as this is for work and any sort of download requires IT intervention, which is always a roadblock. Any help would be appreciated.

Solved the issue. I had to put the .exe file in the cwd and just run it without any arguments.
